# get ordered items from last 10 days of specific customer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, products

I am looking for collection which have number of products that ordered by specific customer. If anyone have any suggestion please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get all order of cutomer last 10 days.

```
$customer_id=10;
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-10 days',strtotime()));

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));

$ordersIds =$orders->getAllIds();
```

Then count number of product order on that orders.

```
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
   $collection->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('in' => $ordersIds));//order_id exist in array
   $collection ->getSelect()
                ->columns('SUM(qty_ordered) as total_qty')
                ->group('product_id');
    echo $collection->getFirstItem()->getTotalQty();

    foreach($collection as $collect)
     {
        echo $collection->getTotalQty();
     }
```

> Not tested  code only giving you general idea.

Comment: internal server error coming..where itemCollection varible define?

Comment: @Ramsystematix updated code..

Comment: Yup! working for me.

Comment: Hi can u give me some idea on how can i get total order amount , instaed of product details. I want the grand total of all the orders within 10 days